# Como buscar um valor entre um range passado

Tags: php, lógica

Tenho que achar se o valor (**5.55** por exemplo) existe em um matriz e saber em qual range dessa matriz esta, e me trazer o id do range.

Eu tinha feito um teste e parecia estar funcionando e quando entrou um valor **0** (zero) já quebrou a minha lógica, depois fiz uma alteração e esta funcionando, mas dai não sei se tem alguma forma melhor para se fazer.

```
<?php
    $precisao = 0.000001;

    $matriz = array(
            array('id'=> 1 , 'vl_inicial' => 0.00, 'vl_final', 19.55),
            array('id'=> 2 , 'vl_inicial' => 19.56, 'vl_final', 28.23),
            array('id'=> 3 , 'vl_inicial' => 30.00, 'vl_final', 100.00)
        );

    $valor = 5.55;

    foreach($matriz as $m) {

        if( in_array($valor, range($m['vl_inicial'], $m['vl_final'])) || 
            (($valor - $m['vl_inicial']) > $precisao) AND (($valor - $m['vl_final']) <= $precisao) )
        {
            return $m['id'];
        }            
    }

    return FALSE;
```

Comment: Por que não fazer duas comparações somente? tem um array com os valores e precisa de saber se o numero existe no array, ou somente se está dentro de um intervalo entre dois numeros?

Comment: @Sergio então, fiz umas alterações na minha dúvida que agora espero que fique mais claro. Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.range.php#refsect1-function.range-parameters), mais especificamente na descrição do parâmetro `$step`:

> **Descrição**
>
> ```
> array range ( mixed $low , mixed $high [, number $step ] )
> ```
>
> Cria um array contendo uma faixa de elementos
>
> **Parâmetros** 
>   [...]
>
> *step*
>
> Se o parâmetro step for especificado, será usado como o incremento entre os elementos da sequência. step deve ser um inteiro positivo. Se
>   não for especificado, step terá valor igual a 1.

Ou seja, você está usando a função `range` e está esperando um resultado diferente.

Para verificar se o valor está dentro de um intervalo, basta um simples `if` com as duas pontas.

```
<?php

$valor = 5.55;

$matriz = array(
        array('id'=> 1 , 'vl_inicial' => 0.00, 'vl_final', 19.55),
        array('id'=> 2 , 'vl_inicial' => 19.56, 'vl_final', 28.23),
        array('id'=> 3 , 'vl_inicial' => 30.00, 'vl_final', 100.00)
);

foreach($matriz as $intervalo) {

    if( ($valor >=  $intervalo['vl_inicial']) && ($valor <= $intervalo['vl_final']) )
    {
        // return $m['id'];
    }            
}
```

Comment: Então, tinha tentado resumir um pouco do meu problema e com isso seria exatamente a sua resposta mesmo, o mais simples possível, mas eu preciso achar o valor em um range mas dentro de uma matriz. Me desculpe por me interpretar mal.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz editado, basicamente a resposta é a mesma: o range não é a solução.

Comment: Uma coisa simples que não sei pq fui complicar né!? Obrigado

Comment: As vezes só precisamos de uma visão de fora do problema que queremos resolver :)

Comment: Bem isso mesmo... Por isso que resolvi postar aqui meu problema.. da forma que mostrei estava funcionando, mas para eu mesmo entender estava complicado.

Comment: E fiz uma alteração na sua resposta, pois precisava ser feito o teste de igualdade não só no valor final mas também no valor inicial.